# Last word in UILabel is lost

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uilabel

I have a simple `UILabel` with some usual constraints.

When I have a small enough text that fits in a line, it renders fine:

[image: One line text]

```
text = "Noodles Con Salsa Cremosa De algo"
```

When I have a big enough text that should flow to the next line, it renders fine again:

[image: Two line text]

```
text = "Noodles Con Salsa Cremosa De algoalgoalgo"
```

But strangely, when I have a text of specific size (that barely exceeds one line and must flow to the next line) the last word is lost (It's neither in the first line nor is there any second line!)

[image: Barely two line text]

```
text = "Noodles Con Salsa Cremosa De algoalgo"
```

What is happening to the last word ("algoalgo")? How can I make it work?

**Edit**:
Heres's the code for views and constraints:

```
// Views:
private let quantityLabel = UILabel()
private let nameLabel = UILabel()
private let descriptionLabel = UILabel()
private let priceLabel = UILabel()
private let infoStackView = UIStackView()

//View setup:
self.addSubview(self.quantityLabel)
self.addSubview(self.infoStackView)
self.addSubview(self.priceLabel)

self.infoStackView.addArrangedSubviews([
  self.nameLabel,
  self.descriptionLabel])

self.nameLabel.numberOfLines = .zero
self.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = .zero

self.infoStackView.axis = .vertical
self.infoStackView.spacing = 4.0

// Constraints:
self.quantityLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
self.quantityLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
  make.leading.equalToSuperview().inset(16.0)
  make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(10.0)
}
self.infoStackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
  self.bottomPadding = make.bottom.equalToSuperview().inset(Constants.customPadding).constraint
  make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(10)
  make.leading.equalTo(self.quantityLabel.snp.trailing).offset(8.0)
}
self.priceLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
self.priceLabel.snp.makeConstraints { make in
  make.leading.equalTo(self.infoStackView.snp.trailing).offset(8.0)
  make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(10.0)
  make.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(16.0)
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that your label view is nested in another view.

Comment: Yes, it is nested. I simplified the constraints for the sake of the question. Is nesting the cause of this?

Comment: Probably yes. Why do you need it as a subview?

Comment: Because there are other subviews (like description) that must be aligned vertically beneath the name. So grouping them in one `UIStackView` was easier.

Comment: What lineBreakMode are you using?

Comment: It's the default one (word wrapping). Though I played with other ones and there was no difference in the result.

Comment: The default lineBreakMode is byTruncatingTail but you should at least see the “…”

Answer (score -1):

I still don't understand what was going on, but it got fixed by setting hugging and content compression priorities to the views at left and right:

```
quantityLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
nameLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
priceLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
```

Comment: I have seen this same phenomenon and your solution is right. But without a complete and accurate description of all the constraints and views and superviews, this Q and A is useless. Change the question to allow the issue to be reproduced. Do not simplify away all the important stuff. Be specific and complete.

Comment: @matt OK, you are right. I added complete code.